# Sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+\frac{1}{2})}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+\frac{1}{2})}$ i am trying to solve an integral and this ended up being last part I need, Wolfram alpha gives $4-2\ln{4}$ but I don't know how they actually got that value. can anyone help or give a starting point? telescoping series didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_n = \dfrac{4}{2n} - \dfrac{4}{2n + 1}$.

Comment: I tried to write it out but there is no pattern... would digamma function work